# HTML IF function with date.time

Tags: python, html, django, datetime, if-statement

In my Django/Python app I have an queryset with 3 conditions:

```
queryset = Post.objects.filter(verifikacija='False', status='Zatvorena', date_zatvoreno__lte=datetime.now(pytz.utc) - timedelta(days=30))
```

Now, I need to make those same conditions in my HTML IF function.

```
{% if user.is_superuser or user.is_staff %}
   {% if object.status == 'Zatvorena' and post.verifikacija != 'True' and post.date_zatvoreno__lte == datetime.now(pytz.utc) - timedelta(days=30) %}
           <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'post-delete' object.id %}">Delete</a>
   {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Problem is, I don't know how to check time or how to calculate time in HTML. Do I need to write a seperate script or?

Comment: You need a [template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-template-tags/) for this, if this task repeats often, or switch to Jinja2 template engine. However, if you need this functionality only in limited cases, just preprocess items on backend. Django templates do not support any logic in templates (which is a questionable decision, but it's what we have).

Comment: You might evaluate it in Python and pass in to the template context instead of writing a custom template tag to evaluate it during template rendering. If it's related to an object instance, add an object method invoked by the template to evaluate it.

Comment: Can you share where object and post context coming from?

Comment: you should do all calculations in function before sending to template

Comment: can you give me an example how can I sent data via template? My code so far is 'class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post' How can I send at least a BOOL, which I could use in my If function.